# How do I bind multi-values with 'if let'?

Tags: swift

How do I bind multi-values with `if let`?

My two values are:

```
var str1: String?
var str2: String? = “str2”
```

I would like to use `if let` to get the values of `str1` and `str2`. How can I do that with only one `if let` sentence?

```
if let …… {
 // get str1 value and str2 value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `,` (comma) to separate them like this:

```
var str1: String?
var str2: String?

if let _str1 = str1, let _str2 = str2 {
    // Do something with _str1 and _str2
}
```

Comment: Second `let` is not required. Just `if let _str1 = str1, _str2 = str2`.